# "Depois que perdeu o emprego meu marido está fazendo bico para nos sustentar"

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, expressões-idiomáticas

Como seria essa frase interpretada em Portugal?  Teria dois significados?
Em pt-BR /fazer bico/fazer um bico/fazer uns bicos/ significa fazer alguns serviços avulsos, de qualquer natureza, para complementar a renda em momentos de crise.  Um ouvinte português entenderia a frase acima como tendo apenas esse significado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, cuidado!

Em Portugal, em Portugal, chamamos a isso "fazer um biscate", "**fazer uns biscates**", ou "fazer umas biscatadas".

"Fazer um bico" é imediata e principalmente "fazer um felácio".
Vê esta t-shirt jocosa:

[image: t-shirt jocosa «faz-me um bico», do site wishirt]

A interpretação inicial dessa frase seria:

> Desde que perdeu o emprego que o meu marido tem dado sexo oral para nos sustentar.

Provavelmente o ouvinte estranharia essa mensagem, dentro do contexto e do nível de formalidade da conversa, e então suspeitaria que no Brasil talvez haja um significado diferente para essa expressão...
Porque não seria esperado que alguém expusesse assim uma atitude que seria considerada desesperada e de último recurso, por ser mal vista pela sociedade.

Suponho que essa frase soasse tão estranha a um português como esta frase soaria a um brasileiro, particularmente se dita por um homem:

> Tenho frio, vou vestir uma camisola.

Comment: "Fazer biscate" no Brasil tem um significado bastante similar a "fazer bico" aí.

Comment: Nao percebi essa do vou vestir uma camisola. O que é que os brasileiros associam a isso mesmo?

Comment: @BrunoCosta, camisola é o nome dado a um tipo de roupa de dormir das mulheres (vide google images).

Comment: Uma resposta que nos faz rir é sempre bom.  +1

Comment: @RamonMelo    Para falantes de português como uma segunda língua, vale a pena explicar que: sim, fazer uns biscates pode significar ter algumas relações extraconjugais (acho que ficou tudo junto com o AO.  Será?) Mas é bom frisar que o significado mais antigo, e ainda mais comum, é fazer uns serviços avulsos para ganhar dinheiro.  Geralmente distingui-se um significado do outro pelo contexto e por um toque de malícia na fala.

Comment: @BrunoCosta uma camisola brasileira é uma camisa de noite... e pois claro, os brasileiros riram-se de mim. ;)

Comment: Em Portugal "fazer bico" é depresiativo.

Comment: @ClMend, é sim. Achas que isso não é claro que chegue, na resposta?

Comment: @ANeves Sim, considero que a resposta abrange .

Comment: Já agora, a maneira mais normal de dizer/escrever aquilo é "tem feito [sexo oral]" e não "tem dado [sexo oral]". Mas preferi usar "dar" por achar que fica mais claro e explícito que é um ato de "vender", de fazer a outrem.